# What happens to the value in the $_POST array after it has been retrieved once?

Tags: php

I noticed that if I make a statement such as

```
$user = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_again = $_POST['user_name'];
```

the first variable `$user` gets the value returned in `$_POST['user_name']`, but the second variable `$user_again` stores nothing, does this mean, one can only make references to the `POST array` only once or some part of my code is buggy??

Comment: BTW, Have you checked your syntax?

Comment: I have tried to verify my syntax numerous times even logic, do u want to see a snippet?? thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

`$user-again` is Syntactically wrong in your code because its violation of the syntax of `PHP` which is:- You cannot use the character `-` while declaring variables or functions. So your code should be something like bekow:-

```
$user = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_again = $_POST['user_name'];
```

You can use `$_POST variable` many times within single script till the execution is not completed:-

https://eval.in/531265

Comment: You can use it multiple time (`$_POST` variable). check:-  https://eval.in/531265

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$user-again` is violating the syntax of PHP.

You cannot use the character - while declaring variables or functions, etc..

So The `$user-again` tries to store the value but as there is a syntax error it won't be able to.

So the correct syntax would be `$user_again = $_POST["user_name"];`

- I would recommend you to use a decent IDE, it can help you fix minor bugs, etc!